# HTML5 Video not rendering on Safari & Firefox with Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, safari

Im trying to display some static HTML5 video in my Angular app. It plays without issues in Chrome but not on Safari or Firefox.

```
<video class="masthead-video w100 m-w100" autoplay loop muted>
    <source src="public/img/test.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="public/img/test.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="public/img/test.ogv" type="video/ogg">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Loading this markup into a browser as simple HTML (no angular or any other markup) allows it to play on Safari and Firefox normally without issues.

Ive tried using `ng-src` instead (even though I shouldnt have to since Im not using dynamic paths) but it didnt help.

Does anyone know of any issues when using HTML5 video with Angular.js?

Comment: `It plays without issues in Chrome but not on Safari or Firefox` - so what issues do you get on Firefox? Any useful information in the browsers **developer** tools console?

Comment: I get a few "resource failed to load" errors `[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (angular.min.js.map, line 0)` but its looking for angular files with `.map` extensions ... I dont know why. angular and all other functions load without issues nonetheless

Comment: that shouldn't be an issue - .map files are helpful for debugging minified js. One thing of note: you've tagged the question `javascript` - yet you've posted no javascript

Comment: I suspect interference with angular.js is causing this issue, hence the javascript tag

Answer (score 0):

Use [$sce](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) for trust source url .

```
$scope.trustSrc = function (src) {
                return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(src);
            };

  $scope.src= public/img/test.mp4;


Html Content



 <video class="masthead-video w100 m-w100" autoplay loop muted>
        <source ng-src="{{trustSrc(src)}}"  type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
```

appy this way for your code.